# Is there a program to convert an Access 2010 DB to an Access 2003 DB?

Tags: ms-access-2010, ms-access-2003

I've spent the last week making a nice database for a project and my boss forgot to inform me that it needs to be in Access 2003 for the client. Is there a way to seamlessly convert from 2010 to 2003 with a program?

Comment: Umm, did you try opening the database in Access 2010 and using `File > Save & Publish > Save Database As` to save it as an "Access 2002-2003 Database"?

Comment: At a minimum, Gord's suggestion will allow you to determine whether your 2010 db uses features which are not supported with the 2003 MDB format ... so should be the first step at least.